# How to switch select between buttons using only keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to keep my fingers on the keyboard as much as possible and would like to be completely mouse-free in some applications, such as `Sublime Text`.  E.g., I can initiate a file opening or closing using just the keyboard but I do not know how to navigate close or open file dialogs using the keyboard alone.  More specifically, how do I switch between selected buttons?  E.g. tabbing works in other OSs I am familiar with (e.g. Windows and Linux KDE) but here I cannot tab between Save and Cancel buttons when I want to close a file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the tab key between save and cancel buttons works for OS X too. You only have to enable it:

1. Go to System Preferences
2. Go To Keyboard
3. Go to the tab Keyboard Short
4. On the bottom of the window, set the radio button to "All controls":

[image: Full Keyboard Access]

From now on, when you see a OK/Cancel window the OK button is blue and can be pressed using the return key, and the cancel button has a outline which can be pressed using the space bar:

[image: Demo]

But the real trick is: You are now able to press the tab key to move the outline to another button and hit the space bar to press the highlighted button.

Comment: I did that I am able to shift selection but when I am on the "Do Not Save' button (i.e. when the button has a highlighted outline like your 'Annuleer'), the fully outlined button is still 'Save' so if I hit <kbd>Return</kbd> it still goes to Save

Comment: Yes, the button pressed using the return key will always be the Save button in your case; you can't change which button is pressed using the return key. But you can press other buttons using tab and the space bar.

Comment: that is kindof awkward but it worked

Comment: You can often, but not always, use Cmd+[initial] to hit buttons. For example, if you close an unsaved file and are offered "Save" and "Don't Save," you can hit Cmd+S to save and Cmd+D for don't save. Works in most cases, AFAIK.

Comment: Alternatively, if you prefer to keep you `Tab` behave normally and would like it to select *All Controls*, then you can just press `Alt+Tab`. Most of times you don’t want `Tab` navigate through all the button on screen.

Comment: @sayzlim — Your comment is contradictory. As for pressing Option Tab (Alt Tab), this does not navigate between buttons.

Answer (score 1):

A common shortcut for a Cancel button is <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>. (i.e. Command and period a.k.a. full stop).

Comment: The command I see here is not Apple Period as intended, but Apple Hyphen.

Comment: More commonly : `Esc`.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text 3 (OSX 10.10.5)

`Enter` = select highlighted option (e.g. "Open", "Save"...)

`Esc` = cancel dialog

`Cmd+D` = select alternate (outlined) option (e.g. "Don't Save"...)